# Second Fundamental form for geodesic sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose $M$ is a Riemannian manifold with constant sectional curvature K. Consider the the geodesic sphere with sufficient small radius $\delta$ such the the exponential map is diffeomorphism. I would like to show that the second fundamental form of this isometric embedding with outward unit normal is proportional to the induced metric on the geodesic sphere. I just show that the geodesic sphere also has constant sectional curvature and its metric is proportional to the canonical metric of a sphere. But I cannot make any further progress right now.

Comment: Have you looked at the Gauss equation?

Comment: I tried the Gauss Equation and it works. Thank you so much Professor Shifrin! Your book really brought me a lot of insights when I had my first course about differential geometry.